# how to fix my firebase hosting that I try to deploy?

Tags: firebase, hosting, web-deployment

I have a personal website from another company's domain and linked firebase host.
I received an email from firebase "you need to verification" but I missed it then my website stop running.

When I tried to redeploy but I completely forgot step by step I don't know what I have to do first?.

Here are photos that might be helpful.
**My webpage alert:**
[image]

**My Terminal:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll write down the steps from scratch i.e. from the starting firebase to deploying the website.

Steps:-

1. write `firebase init` in the terminal of your project folder
2. the firebase setup gets initialized and asks for different permissions.
3. The first thing it asks the user, **Are you ready to proceed?**
4. Reply it with a **y** or **yes**
5. Then between different firebase services choose the hosting by bringing the selector on it by using arrow keys and press the spacebar when the selector is on the Hosting
6. Press enter after it
   7.Select if you want to use an existing project or create one. Also, there are two more options there like add Firebase to an existing Google Platform project and Don't set up a default project
7. Select the **Use an existing project** in your case and select the project that you want to use. The project must already be created in the firebase console.
8. After selecting a default directory, press enter to move forward.
9. Then it asks three questions, answer them according to you.
   i.   What do you want to use as your public directory?
   ii.  Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N)
   iii. Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N)
10. Add the firebase SDK to your index.html file
11. After answering all these, write `firebase deploy`
12. After following all the steps, your website will be hosted.

Hope this would be helpful for you!!